Is it ok to pass MutableState<T> as Parameter to a Composable?
I've been learning how to use Jetpack Compose, coming from a project developed using SwiftUI. The goal is to port an iOS app to Android.
I try to stick to best practices while keeping the code as similar as possible to the original SwiftUI code.
In SwiftUI, you can share a @State variable with subviews by declaring the variable as @Binding in the subview, and then prepending a dollar sign when passing it from the parent view, like so:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isOn = false  // Parent state
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ToggleView(isOn: $isOn)  // Passing a Binding to the child view
            
            Text(isOn ? "The switch is ON" : "The switch is OFF")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ToggleView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool  // Binding property to update the parent's state
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle("Switch", isOn: $isOn)  // Use the Binding here
            .padding()
    }
}

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

The official Jetpack Compose documentation, on the other hand, recommends following the Unidirectional Data Flow pattern, like so:
@Composable
fun ContentView() {
    var isOn by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }  // Parent state

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ToggleView(isOn = isOn, onToggle = { isOn = it })  // Pass state and callback to child

        Text(text = if (isOn) "The switch is ON" else "The switch is OFF")
    }
}

@Composable
fun ToggleView(isOn: Boolean, onToggle: (Boolean) -> Unit) {  // Accept state and callback
    Switch(
        checked = isOn,  // Read the state
        onCheckedChange = onToggle  // Call callback to update parent state
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewContentView() {
    ContentView()
}

While this approach works, I find it somewhat cumbersome and error-prone to require a lambda for every state variable that needs to be updated inside a subview.
So, instead of passing the value of MutableState to subviews, I tried passing the entire MutableState object, like so:
@Composable
fun ContentView() {
    val isOnState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }  // Parent state
    var isOn by isOnState

    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
        ToggleView(isOnState=isOnState)  // Pass state and callback to child

        Text(text = if (isOn) "The switch is ON" else "The switch is OFF")
    }
}

@Composable
fun ToggleView(isOnState: MutableState<Boolean>) {  // Accept state and callback
    var isOn by isOnState
    Switch(
        checked = isOn,  // Read the state
        onCheckedChange = { isOn = it }  // Call callback to update parent state
    )
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewContentView() {
    ContentView()
}

This approach seems to work, but I have the impression that it's not advisable to do it this way.
So, I have the following questions:

Are there any pitfalls I'm missing?
Is it okay to pass MutableState<T> as a parameter in order to better replicate the way SwiftUI handles state bindings?

Thank you very much for any insights you can provide regarding this!

There's never a good reason to have MutableState in your API. Instead you got two options.
fun Foo(state: T, setState: (T) -> Unit)
// or
fun Foo(getState: () -> T, setState: (T) -> Unit)

Use the first for normal scenarios.
Second for when you need to defer the read for optimization reasons.
There's no reason to ever pass MutableState directly. You are only making the API harder to work with for callers that don't have MutableState at hand. And that very often includes previews.
p.s. there is also the option of having a state holder class which holds internally mutable state, but that should be reserved for scenarios where you need that state object for other reasons too.
Read more over at https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state-hoisting#classes-as-state-owner

While passing the state as a mutable state works, I'd say it is an anti-pattern as it is not recommended.
When porting a code from one language/framework to another, you need to keep in mind that the frameworks involved do things differently. Having said that, it is always a good idea to follow the pattern established for the said framework/language.
In your case, while that could be the accepted way of doing things in SwiftUI, it is not the way you should do it in Jetpack Compose.
By passing the state directly, you could introduce hard to find bugs in your code. My advice is you should approach this using the recommended practices for Jetpack Compose.
